# Intuition behind the Minkowski dimension and measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

Can someone please explain the intuition behind the Minkowski dimension and measure?

I am using the definition of the Minkowski measure as 
$$M^{\alpha}(K)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\mu(V_{\epsilon}(K))}{\epsilon^{n-\alpha}} $$
Where $K\subset\mathbb{R^n}$, $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$, and $\mu$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $V_{\epsilon}$ is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $K$.

And the definition of the Minkowski dimension is 
$$\dim_{M}(K)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{N_{\epsilon}(K)}{\ln(\frac1{\epsilon})}$$
Where $N_{\epsilon}(K)$ is the minimum number of non-overlapping $n$-dimensional boxes of side length $\epsilon$ necessary to cover $K$.

I know these are largely used when working with fractals, but how does the notion of counting boxes relate.

Comment: Related --- [Intuitive meaning of fractal dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057342/intuitive-meaning-of-fractal-dimension) AND [Box-Counting Dimension with finite resolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365941/box-counting-dimension-with-finite-resolution). Also, [these notes by Erin Pearse](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/docs/dimension.pdf) seem to me that they could be useful (e.g. pp. 8-13).